# Join 4 tables with common field in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have four tables named tblproducts, tblprospecification, tblcomspecification and tblledtvpecification.

- The fields of tblproducts are proid, product_code, product_name,
  pro_img, pro_resize_img, pro_thumb_img and it stores products
  details.
- The second table is tblprospecification stores the mobile specifications and it has column speid, proid, in_the_box ,model_number, model_name, color, browse_type, sim_type.
- The third table is tblcomspecification for storing computer specification and its column are comspecificid,proid, modelname, color, series etc. and the fourth column istblledtvpecification for storing ledtv specification and its column are tvspecificid, modelname, dsize, stype_id, hd_techno.

I am using the query below enter

```
$query= $this->db->select( 'tblproducts.proid as pro_id, product_code, product_name, pro_img, pro_resize_img, pro_thumb_img, tblprospecification.proid as product_id , in_the_box ,model_number, model_name, tblprospecification.color as mobile_color, browse_type, sim_type ,tblcomspecification.proid  as product_id, tblcomspecification.modelname as com_moledname, series, tblcomspecification.color as com_color,  tblledtvpecification.proid, tblledtvpecification.modelname as ledtv_modelname, dsize,stype_id, hd_techno')
->from('tblproducts')
->join('tblprospecification','tblproducts.proid = tblprospecification.proid ' ,'left')
->join('tblcomspecification','tblproducts.proid = tblcomspecification.proid', 'left')
->join('tblledtvpecification','tblproducts.proid = tblledtvpecification.proid' ,'left')
->where('tblproducts.proid',$proid)
->get();
return $query->result();
```

When I execute the query, it will return the data after join from tblproducts and tblprospecification only. It returns blank  data for tblledtvpecification, tblcomspecification.

Comment: I don't see nothing wrong with your query. You are performing a 'left join' which will return 'null' when the query does not match any field based on 'proid' column you used on the join and where clauses. Make sure you have data associated witht the proid in all the table otherwise it will return 'null' for the ones you don't have records related to 'proid = $proid'

Comment: when i joined the only two tables  like tblproducts and tblprospecification / tblproducts and tblcomspecification/ tblproducts and tblledtvpecification all combinations are working properly. But it creating problem to me that for displaying the specifications of Mobile Phones, Computer and Ledtv i have to use three different pages. But i want to display in one page.

Comment: Major issue with the above query is that it is not display the data from the tblproducts for the category computer and LED TV. It only displays data for mobile phones only.